# Variant Calling Pipeline Parallelization: ERROR - "sbatch: not found Error submitting jobscript (exit code 127)"

Tags: parallel-processing, hpc, snakemake, snakeyaml, vcf-variant-call-format

I developed a pipeline written in Snakemake for genome variant calling analysis.
I'm trying to [parallelize it now](https://github.com/ray2g/vcall_biodata/blob/master/vcall-pipe2_cluster.snake), in order to be ran in a HPC cluster with multiple nodes.

I have a [configuration file](https://github.com/ray2g/vcall_biodata/blob/master/config_pipeline2_cluster.yaml) (yaml) where the paths of the files are defined.

When I execute the pipeline with the command:

```
shifter --volume=/home/ubuntu/vcall_docker_gatk4_bottle/:/mnt/  \
--image=docker:ray2g/vcall_biodata:1.5.1 \
snakemake --snakefile /mnt/vcall-pipe3_cluster.snake \
-p /mnt/genome/resources_broad_hg38_v0_Homo_sapiens_assembly38.fasta.sa \
-j 24 \
--cluster 'sbatch -p {params.partition} --mem {resources.mem_mb}mb --cpus-per-task {resources.cpus}' \
--forceall
```

I'm getting this ERROR:

```
Building DAG of jobs...
Using shell: /bin/bash
Provided cluster nodes: 24
Unlimited resources: cpus, mem_mb
Job counts:
        count   jobs
        1       bwa_index
        1

[Wed Jan 27 14:30:40 2021]
Job 0: Building index -> /mnt/genome/resources_broad_hg38_v0_Homo_sapiens_assembly38.fasta.sa

bwa index /mnt/genome/resources_broad_hg38_v0_Homo_sapiens_assembly38.fasta
/bin/sh: 1: sbatch: not found
Error submitting jobscript (exit code 127):Shutting down, this might take some time.
```

Any one could help me ?

Comment: Could you confirm your HPC is slurm and not something else? `sbatch` is specific to slurm HPC.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes the HPC workflow manager is Slurm.

Comment: So you are running the snakemake inside a container, but this container doesn't have slurm/`sbatch` installed which is why you get this error. Even if you could somehow install slurm/sbatch inside the container, I'm not sure if (or how well) it can interact with slurm in your HPC for scheduling jobs and get their status.

Comment: In the past, we have thought about this route but soon abandoned it as it appeared to be lot of struggle to get it to work, if at all. Instead, we ended up adopting the [route of singularity+conda](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/deployment.html#combining-conda-package-management-with-containers). Your pipeline won't be containerized in this method, but the jobs spawned by the pipeline will run inside containers. I find this to be a reasonable compromise.